# get server time on the client side in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, .net, datetime, localization, timezone

I want to use, on the client side, dates as they are on the server side.
for example- if the current time on the server side is '2011-09-21 15:00:00', I want to be able to get a javascript `Date` object with that value ('15:00:00'), even if the client is in a different time zone.
what i've tried so far:
suppose the server time is '15:00:00' and client time is '17:00:00', The `Date` object I get on the client side always contains '16:00:00', for some reason.
here's what i've tried:
1. sending a .net DateTime object to the client (it gets serialized as 
`"Date\12345...\"`), and on the client side converting it to a `Date` object:

```
function parseServerDate(strDate) {
    return new Date(parseInt(strDate.substr(6)));
}
```

OR converting the .net `DateTime` object into a UTC number:

```
    // returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 (useful for converting C# dates to JS dates)
    public static double UnixTicks(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        DateTime d2 = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - epoch.Ticks);
        return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
```

and then creating a new `Date` object:
`new Date(milliseconds)` or `new Date().setTime(milliseconds)`, both of which produced the same result as above.

should I maybe send the server's timezone offset as well, and handle the difference in the client side?
What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Date objects created on the client will be in the timezone of the client, i.e. they will use the client's timezone offset. You can manually change the timezone offset, or you can just create a date object that matches the time on the server and ignore the offset, unless you are trying to do date arithmetic between the client and server.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about display, why do you need a Date object client-side? Why not simply have the server send the datetime as string and let the client display it as is?

Comment: becuase it's not just about display :) i spared the details since they aren't relevant to the question